# How to Merge Lines from 2 Text File without creating a Line Break in Batch Command

Tags: batch-file, merge

i am looking for a code to merge 2 text files without creating a line break.

currently i am using this code.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set fd1=\folderpath1\
set fd2=\folderpath2\
set MrgFiles=\outputfolder\
pushd "%fd1%"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "!fd1!"') do (
    if exist "!fd2!\%%a" (
        type "%%~fa">"!MrgFiles!\%%a"
        echo.>>"!MrgFiles!\%%a"
        type "!fd2!\%%a">>"!MrgFiles!\%%a"
    )
)
popd
```

my setup is currently like this

```
Folder 1 has 100 files in it.
Each file has 1 line
Example: 
Line 1

Folder 2 has 100 files in it.
Each file has 1 line.
Example:
Line a
```

the code above manage to merge the files together and output nicely, with the second line on a new line break.

but i need the newly merged lines to be in a single line.

i tried to remove the code `echo.>>"!MrgFiles!\%%a"`
but then it merges both lines without space.

how can i batch merge the lines into

```
line 1 line a
line 2 line b
```

sorry for my bad explanation, i think the code is almost complete but i just cant figure out a way to merge the lines into a single line.

Please help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easy trick to reading a text file into a variable.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /p "text1="<file1.txt
set /p "text2="<file2.txt
>merged.txt echo(%text1% %text2%
```

That'll take the contents of file1.txt and file2.txt, join them together on one line, and dump the concatenated line to merged.txt.

The `set /p` command listens for input on stdin.  The `<` dumps the contents of a file to stdin, into the waiting `set /p`.  See [this page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php) for more info on batch file redirection.

---

**Edit:** Well, apparently your lines are too large for that method to work.  That's surprising, as I really thought batch variables could handle much more than 2500 characters.  I was going to suggest `set /P "= "<NUL` to echo a space without a line break, but `set /P` refuses to pass a space (or a tab) unless I add non-whitespace characters.  I tried using [dbenham's second method](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2124&mobile=on) of capturing a backspace character to a variable and echoing it out to the text file, but that didn't work either.

Long story short, I gave up and decided to use a Howitzer to swat this fly.  S.O. is not intended to be a free coding service, but blast it, I refuse to be defeated by your problem.  Here's a hybrid batch / JScript script that does what you want.  Save it with a .bat extension.

```
@if (@a==@b) @end   /* begin JScript multiline comment

:: batch portion

@echo off
setlocal
set "fd1=\folderpath1\"
set "fd2=\folderpath2\"
set "MrgFiles=\outputfolder\"
pushd "%fd1%"

for %%a in (*) do (
    if exist "%fd2%\%%~a" (
        cscript /nologo /e:Jscript "%~f0" "%%~a" "%fd2%\%%~a" "%MrgFiles%\%%~a"
    )
)

popd

goto :EOF

:: end batch portion / begin JScript hybrid */
var fso = new ActiveXObject('scripting.filesystemobject'),
    file1 = fso.OpenTextFile(WSH.Arguments(0), 1),
    file2 = fso.OpenTextFile(WSH.Arguments(1), 1),
    merge = fso.CreateTextFile(WSH.Arguments(2), true);

merge.Write(file1.ReadLine() + ' ' + file2.ReadLine());
file1.Close();
file2.Close();
merge.Close();
```

Comment: how do i integrate your code into what i have? from what i see, your code needs a manual input for the file name. my files in both folders are already in the format of file001.txt, file002.txt, etc.

Comment: i tried your code, it does merge the lines together with a space, but it somehow strips part of my text away. the textfile i have contains bout 2500 characters per line. the code that i posted on top manage to merge the entire text. but we are getting close. is there anyway to change my existing code to add a space or do a backspace?

Comment: Do the lines in your text files end in a trailing newline?  If not, then you can `copy file1 + file2 mrgfiles\joined`.  The `+` will merge files, but if file1 has a line break at the end, file2 will still be appended after that line break -- in other words, on the second line.

Comment: no trailing newline. all text file have 1 line only. is there any workaround using my existing code? just need to add a space in between the merged lines.

Comment: @einstein There, I fixed it.  :P

Comment: didnt know it could go that far. i thought some minor editing would fix the space issue. anyway, it work! amazingly. thanks rojo! thank you so much. i owe you one mate.